# JDK8u20 compilation error with provided dependency

Tags: java, maven, java-8

I use maven (3.2.1) to build our project. My project depends on some propretiary libraries that we have in local maven repo. Those libraries are declared with provided scope (because we don't need them in distribution). Our dependencies depends, of course, on some other libs, e.g. apache-scxml lib, but our code don't do anything with any class from apache-scxml. And in JDK8u20 we cannot build our system anymore, it fails with exception:
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project <myproject>: Compilation failure
[ERROR] <myclass>.java:[47,45] error: cannot access SCXMLListener`

But project builds completely fine with JDK8u5 and JDK8u11.
I tried to find some info and only thing I found is here: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/FORGE-2019
but I don't think its the same, or at least I cannot understand it. Can someone explain to me what can be the reason that it compiles with JDK8u11 and not with u20?

Comment: There are several issues with Java 8u20...in newer versions there have been fixes. Furthermore don't use such an old version of maven-compiler-plugin. See also http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MCOMPILER-228 (Update to new Java 8 version).

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks for response. For some reasons I am using oracle JDK and for my linux distribution there is no update yet. According to what you wrote, can I assume that it's a bug and should be fixed in next JDK release?

Comment: There are already early access builds out......http://jdk8.java.net/download.html http://www.java.net/download/jdk8u40/changes/jdk8u40-b07.html